# 3D hit testing with tolerance

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm using wpf and viewport 3d. Now I can show a cube (as ModelsGroup: two meshes per one cube side, because each of cubes site has own color). I want to detect, when user  hits a cube edge using  mouse click. I know it could be done with Visual Tree Helper, but I must do it with some tolerance. How can I detect hit, if user clicks the point close to edge, but that point is outside mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could adjust the x and y of the press point and test several locations. Many cubes may be hit, that's then up to you how to resolve that.

i.e. could test a pattern of 9:

`t` is tolerance, `x,y` are the coords of the click point

```
x, y
x + t, y
x - t, y
x,     y + t
x,     y - t
x + t, y + t
x + t, y - t
x - t, y + t
x - t, y - t
```